# Delete object property on every response - Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have to delete the password property every time that my API needs to return the user data, in order to prevent security issues.

For instance:

```
routes.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = request.body;

    const authenticateUserService = new AuthenticateUserService();

    const { user, token } = await authenticateUserService.execute({
      email,
      password,
    });

    delete user.password;

    return response.json({ user, token });
  } catch (error) {
    return response.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

And that's repeating for more routes that deal with the user resource. 
Is there a way to make that cleaner instead of always repeating the same logic? Maybe an interceptor

Comment: Can you wrap the functions that return users with a version that always drops the password, and consistently use those wrappers?

Comment: In apostrophecms we were sufficiently worried about this that we chose to store the password hash in a separate location in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.
In my projects, I use middleware chaining to do that kind of thing.
In your code you just need to create a middlewares

In this pattern we will call just 2 middleware per route, but you can have as many as necessary. We will create two middleware for the current `/` route.
route.js

```
import { request } from "express";

first = async (request, response, next) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = request.body;

        const authenticateUserService = new AuthenticateUserService();

        const { user, token } = await authenticateUserService.execute({
          email,
          password,
        });
        request.myuser = user
        request.mytoken = token
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        return response.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
}

second = (request, response, next) => {
    delete request.myuser.password;
    next()
}

third = (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).json({ user: request.myuser, token: request.mytoken });
}

routes.post('/', first, second, third);
```

What we are doing here is the same thing you were doing before, but here we have a middleware `second` that we can reuse in every route we need to remove the password, we just need to put the user and token in our request object to make it accessible from our middleware functions and call `second` to remove the sensible data from our request. That is the idea.

Notice that in `first` and `second` we have the third parameter in middleware called `next` that is where we are doing the middleware chaining. The request goes on that order until it is resolved as a response.

For every middleware you would like to use the `second` middleware you just need to guarantee that the `request.myuser` exists.

Also notice that every time you have more than 1 middleware per route, all middleware must have the `next` function (except the last one).

If I do not made me clear, please let me know and I can update my answer.